# Damped harmonic oscillator Lagrangian $f(t)(\ddot{x}+\alpha\dot{x}+\omega^2x)=0$ determinate a function $f(t)>0$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, friction, dissipation

I'm considering a damped harmonic oscillator 
$$\ddot{x}+\alpha\dot{x}+\omega^2x=0 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \alpha \neq 0$$
I know that this equation could not be a lagrangian equation originated from a lagrangian L$(x,\dot{x},t)$.

Reading about this problem I find that I can determinate a function $f(t)>0$  such as   $$f(t)(\ddot{x}+\alpha\dot{x}+\omega^2x)=0$$
is a lagrangian equation and for this reason I can determinate a lagrangian.

However I don't kwon how to do it. 
I need an analitical expression for the function $f(t)$ ed the lagrangian.